# how to set condition in react router DOM version 6?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to convert this code which has been written in react router v5 to v6 but I don't know how to do it, in general I want to set if the user doesn't have an account, redirect them to registration page an so on.

I'm aware of switch change and redirect the only problem is in this line of code :

```js
<Route exact path="/">
  {user ? <Home /> : <Redirect to="/register" />}
</Route>
```

the whole code:

```
import "./app.scss";
import Home from "./pages/home/Home";
import Register from "./pages/register/Register";
import Watch from "./pages/watch/Watch";
import Login from "./pages/login/Login";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "./authContext/AuthContext";

const App = () => {
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          {user ? <Home /> : <Redirect to="/register" />}
        </Route>
        <Route path="/register">
          {!user ? <Register /> : <Redirect to="/" />}
        </Route>
        <Route path="/login">{!user ? <Login /> : <Redirect to="/" />}</Route>
        {user && (
          <>
            <Route path="/movies">
              <Home type="movie" />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/series">
              <Home type="series" />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/watch">
              <Watch />
            </Route>
          </>
        )}
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: A lot changed from RRDv5 to RRDv6. What have you tried? Provide a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service, so if you haven't tried this yet and you're looking for where to start, see the [Upgrading from v5](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5) guide.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the element prop of v6, you don't need to use an exact prop on `<Route path="/">` anymore. This is because all paths match exactly by default. If you want to match more of the URL because you have child routes use a trailing * as `<Route path="/*" />`.

```
import { BrowserRouter, Navigate, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
.
.
.
return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={user ? <Home /> : <Navigate to="/register" replace />} />
        .
        .
        .
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
)
.
.
.
```

Also you can see more detail in `reactrouter` docs:

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview